# Locally serving filepicker.io JS

Tags: javascript, filepicker.io

We use [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) to handle JavaScript module loading. How often is the source at http://api.filepicker.io/v1/filepicker.js updated? Is it safe (as in it won't cause our app to suddenly break when you make changes) to download and serve locally via such a module loader?

I assume because of the versioning in the directory that on updating the API you'll update the directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, we strongly recommend against storing the filepicker.js locally.

While we try not to change the javascript very often (for caching purposes, for one), we do push out changes occasionally to fix issues that are found or add new features. Occasionally, we will do things that don't affect the external API, but change the way that the library communicates with our servers - in these cases, if you were using a copy stored locally, your implementation would no longer work.

With regard to the "v1" versioning, that is the version number of the API (rather than the js include), to distinguish it from the v0 api that was deprecated in December 2012.

Comment: Not to worry I'll revert to loading externally.